# Function Declaration that removes keywords stored in an array from a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a function declaration that I need to use. Its purpose is to remove various keywords (that should not have been in the string) contained in an array from a string contained in the `console.log`.

This will make the string readable. Please Help, I'm currently learning.

By removing "not", "hello" from the string, this will give "If string includes words in array, remove them JavaScript".

```
function correctString(string, Keywords) {
    let spec1 = Keywords;
    let spec2 = spec1.pop();
    return string.replace(spec2, "");
}

console.log(correctString("If stringnot includes whelloords in array, remove them JavaScript", ["not", "hello"]));
```

I was able to remove the "hello" keyword from the string with the pop method. However, I cannot find a method that removes the other keyword "not" from the string... I tried to use different methods such as `.filter`, `.splice`, `.slice`.

Comment: You can try running the `console.log(...` as many times as the number of items in the Keywords array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish? See this [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and especially the statement in the first paragraph that "The original string is left unchanged." You may also be interested in [replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll).

```js
function correctString(text, Keywords) {
    Keywords.forEach( v => {
      console.log(v + ": " + text.indexOf(v));
      text = text.replace(v,"");
      console.log(text);
      });
    return text;
}


console.log(correctString("If stringnot includes whelloords in array, remove them JavaScript", ["not", "hello"]));
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I noted the use of the forEach method, and the arrow function. Thanks for having also provided MDN webpages. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I probably should have provided a better explanation with the snippet. I. too, had forgotten that the original string is unchanged, but should have remembered since strings are an immutable data type. It is likely not a very efficient method since the string is rewritten for every word in `Keywords` array; but, at the moment, I don't know of another way to accomplish the same. If all the words in `Keywords` array were words in the string, perhaps splitting the string into words and iterating through it once would be better; but that wouldn't work with `whelloords`.